# making a folder public in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

i need to set a folder public with only read permisions in firebase storage, my security rules are

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write:if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /{platos=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

the folder is called platos and im not sure if those rules are secured the others folders must have protection only for logued users

Comment: Depends what you call `secured`. You're allowing anyone that's logged into your firebase project to read and write to all file paths.

Comment: If you're using something like google sign in that's not a problem because only authorized domains will be able to authenticate anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just delete the authentication code `request.auth.uid != null` and give only the read permission.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Removing `request.auth.uid != null` allows users with **no** authentication to read from every file in the bucket. This is highly recommended against. See Lukasz's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

The first rule should concern your folder, because otherwise the first rule is applied which rejects reads:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /platos/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read;
        allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```